# Redirect from email link to page

Tags: reactjs, flask, react-router-dom

So I am currently implementing a "reset password" feature on my website. My application uses JWT for authentication. The application uses React (React Hooks, not components) on the frontend, with `react-router-dom` for the routing, and Flask on the backend.

The backend functionality works fine. A user fills in an email address of the email they wish to reset the password of, and then the backend sends an email with a link to that address they can click (at the moment, once clicked, it just returns an OK response and does nothing else).

My question is, after the link is clicked in their inbox, I want the user to be forwarded to a `/change_password` page where they can fill out a new password.

Once the email link is clicked, how can I then go from the Flask backend, to rendering a specific route in React?

I am using `react-router-dom` client-side routing throughout my application.

I am only asking as it seems a bit strange to have a mix of server-side and client-side rendering for an application. If I can forward to a page in in React, that would be nice.

So my routes are called by index.jsx

**index.jsx**

```js
ReactDOM.render(<AppRouter/>, document.getElementById("app"));
```

**routes.jsx**

```js
const AppRouter = () => {
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  const providerValue = useMemo(() => ({user, setUser}), [user, setUser]);

  return(
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Route exact path='/' component={LandingPage} />
      <Switch>
        <UserContext.Provider value={providerValue}>
          <Route path="/login" component={LoginPage} />
          <Route path="/register" component={RegisterPage} />
          <Route path="/forgotten" component={ForgottenPage} />
          <PrivateRoute path="/home" component={UserApp} />
        </UserContext.Provider>
      </Switch>
      <Redirect from="*" to="/" />
    </BrowserRouter>
  )
}
```

At the moment, Flask just renders `index.html` which has 1 tag element id of `app`.

Any advice would be great.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry not 100% understanding what your current setup is

**Server Side Rendering**
Yes exactly,  send it over then when the button is clicked the token and user id should be sent to the backend and after verification the backend sends back a template which will then be filled out and sent to the api with the token and user ID again (at least how I would do it)

**Client Side Rendering**

The way I would go about this is in my Router have
<Route path "/recoverpassword/:tempToken">{recoverComponent}
And then have the link take you to app.com/recoverpassword/{tempToken}
Then set up a componentDidMount on the recoverComponent which calls the backend making sure the link is active and the token is valid. If it is then use the token to set up a new password.

You could try to use a listener of some sort but if they switch browsers to go to their email inbox just as an example then this won't work. Don't recommend that at all

Comment: Hello, I updated the question and added some code snippets to clarify.
`<Route path "/recoverpassword/:tempToken">{recoverComponent} ` this bit makes sense. But how can I route to that from flask? The clicking of the email verification link will send a response back to flask and not to React.

Comment: In the same way as any other screen no? Whatever setup you have right now to get the register screen to work just do that for the recover password screen. The only difference is that here you just have to check if the temp token is valid

Comment: So when it once the link is clicked, the flask route should do a `redirect('http://myapp.com/change_password') ` and that should redirect to the correct page (assuming the react-route is set up)?  That sounds like it should work. 

Thanks for the advice. It has been helpful.

Comment: Yes but I would route it to redirect('http://myapp.com/change_password/:token') so that you can pass the token back and not have to make more api calls. You're going to need this token sent back to the server since it currently is your auth.

Comment: That's great. Thank you!